# How can I get extra data by Intent using Android annotation?

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I'm really new to Android. I'm trying to pass the data to the text view of another class. But for some reason, it does not appear in the second class / page (the textview didnt change). I was able to do it when I was not using android annotation, but I was told that using annotations is a lot easier so I'm trying to convert it to that but for some reason it isn't working? I might be missing something.

Main 1

```
package com.example.faculty.labactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

@EActivity(R.layout.world)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById(R.id.userName)
    EditText user;


    @Click(R.id.signIn)
    public void signInButton(){

     Main2Activity_.intent().name(user.getText().toString()).start();

   }
```

Main 2

```
package com.example.faculty.labactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Extra;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

@EActivity(R.layout.welcome)
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Extra("name")
String n;

@ViewById(R.id.name)
TextView tv;

Intent in2 = getIntent();

@AfterViews
void home(){
    tv.setText("Hello, " + n + " !");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your receiving Activity (for example MyActivity) you must declare the name of the object you want to receive like that

```
@Extra("name")
String name;
```

To pass data, when you create your intent you must do something like this:

```
Main2Activity_.intent(this).name(user.getText().toString()).start();
```

If you need a more precise solution edit your question to show more of your code.

You can look at the [official doc](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Extras) for a more complete example

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering. I tried following your code, but there is an error in Main2_.intent() -- it said cannot resolve method 'intent()' ?

Comment: If your Activity's name is Main2Activity you must write Main2Activity_.intent() . Read about Android Annotations naming convention ang generated classes naming

Comment: It says that Main2Activity_ has not intent() method?

Comment: try passing it a context or a subclass of it, like your Activity1 reference

Comment: you mean like the this function? eg. Main2Activity_.intent(this).name(user.getText().toString()).start(); -- it still produced an error tho?

Comment: this time, the name has an error -- "Cannot resolve method 'name(java.lang.String)'"

Comment: Use IDE code completion, you will easily solve many of these problems. In your case you must use n(java.lang.String) method because your @Extra annotated filed is named n

Comment: Hi sorry for the really long chat. But when I tried using the code completion, there was no suggested "n" or "name" that appeared. It did tell me to create a new method tho?

Comment: that is another problem, but i don't know how to help you. Keep in mind that in AndroidAnnotations you can always inspect generated  code. In AndroidStudio you can press ctrl + n and write the class name to search, Main2Activity_ for example, and read the generated code (that means obviously look at available methods)

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the dependencies you should add for the annotations to your `project_root/build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` files.

Make sure to check this thread: [what is Android Annotations and why we use Android Annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482215/what-is-android-annotations-and-why-we-use-android-annotations)