# How to convert kotlin or java codes with annotations to simple without annotations codes?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I want to recreate some apps from GitHub using MVVM architecture. But I don't want codes to contain annotations like `@inject`, `@JvmField`,`@JvmStatic`, `@Field` etc. to keep codes simple as possible as understandable for me and beginners.

Is there some general rules or any plugin that by following them one could remove annotations?

**P.s.** [It seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32482215/21193451) some programmers don't like to use annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some general rules or any plugin that by following them one could remove annotations?

No.

> I want to recreate some apps from GitHub using MVVM architecture

Then rewrite them from scratch, using techniques and technologies that do not require annotations. For example, `@Inject` is often used with dependency inversion frameworks like Dagger/Hilt — you would need to use something else (e.g., Koin) or avoid dependency inversion.

> to keep codes simple as possible as understandable for me and beginners

Annotations are not especially complicated, and they are reasonably important for many things in modern Android app development.

> P.s. It seems that some programmers don't like to use annotations.

No, some programmers do not like to use the old Android Annotations library. That is what that question and its answers are referring to, not annotations in general.

Comment: Sorry that I can't upvote due to stackoverflow rules!!!